# IIS: PHP Imagick (working) with Ghostscript (not working)

Tags: php, windows, iis, ghostscript, imagick

I have installed ImageMagick-7.0.10-Q16-HDRI, and gs9.53.3 on Windows Server 2016 Standard.

This snippet:

```
$pages = [];
$im = new \Imagick();
$im->setresolution(150, 150);
$im->readimage("/test.pdf");
for ($i = 0; $i < $im->getnumberimages(); $i++) {
    $im->setiteratorindex($i);
    $im->setimageformat('jpg');
    $im->setImageAlphaChannel(\Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE);
    array_push($pages, addslashes($im->getimageblob()));
}
$im->destroy();
```

results in this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed `The system cannot find the file specified. ' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/794 in .........\dev\gs_test.php:11 Stack trace: #0 E:\inetpub\wwwroot\test-analysis\dev\gs_test.php(11): Imagick->readimage() #1 {main} thrown in .......\dev\gs_test.php on line 11
```

I have tried copying gs4win64c.exe to gs.exe and adding `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.53.3\bin` to PATH, and now get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: PDFDelegateFailed `Error: /undefinedfilename in (C:/Windows/TEMP/magick-8156OUt95Ei0WCah) Operand stack: Execution stack: %interp_exit .runexec2 --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- 2 %stopped_push --nostringval-- --nostringval-- --nostringval-- false 1 %stopped_push Dictionary stack: --dict:737/1123(ro)(G)-- --dict:0/20(G)-- --dict:75/200(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Last OS error: Permission denied GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1 ' @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/794 in .......\dev\gs_test.php:11 Stack trace: #0 ........\dev\gs_test.php(11): Imagick->readimage() #1 {main} thrown in .......\dev\gs_test.php on line 11
```

I'm a bit stuck on what's going on now!  The exact same code works perfectly out of the box on my test Unix server.

Comment: I think this is probably caused by the incompatibility of the version. Try to change the version of Ghostscript and change Ghostscript 9.53.3 to 32-bit.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I have both installed, and I also tried putting gs4win32c.exe in as gs.exe with the same result :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided that I am missing something really important, so for now I have just used Ghostscript directly:

```
// Make sure gswin64c.exe is in %PATH%
// This is used with PHP upload

foreach ($_FILES as $f) {
    shell_exec("gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile={$f['tmp_name']}-page-%03d.jpg -r150x150 -f -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q {$f['tmp_name']}");
    $pages = [];
    foreach (glob("{$f['tmp_name']}-page-[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg") as $page) {
        array_push($pages, addslashes(file_get_contents($page)));
        unlink($page);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The licenses under Windows and Linux are different, please check if you are using the same source of Ghostscript. Because you mentioned that it works normally under Unix server.

[Ghostscript Downloads](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html)

Comment: I definitely have the Windows version installed.  It appears to be some sort of weird permissions issue-- I have tried temporarily adding IIS_IUSRS, IUSR and "IIS AppPool\Default Application Pool" (or whatever it is) as Full Control users to %TEMP% as well, with the same error.